# Advapi32.lib missing from Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, advapi32

My code compiles and links just fine on PC #1 using VS 2013 Pro.  It fails linking on PC #2 using VS 2013 Community Edition.  The failure is three unresolved externals from Advapi32.lib -- CryptAcquireContextW, CryptReleaseContext, and CryptGenRandom.

This leads to several key questions:

1. Why doesn't VS 2013 warn you when it can't find a library that's on the linker input line?
2. Why is Advapi32.lib unavailable in the Community Edition?
3. What can one do to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It is usually required to install a Windows SDK for the targeted Windows version. When installed, It provides additional libraries.

Comment: Thanks David. I tried that and it's definitely a good idea, but it caused a bunch of duplicate symbol and header issues that I'd probably spend a fair amount of time resolving. Luckily (this time) I didn't need to do so.